# Devise + Backbone.js, cannot create new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, devise

Register view is rendered by backbone. When I submit the form to register a new user, I got the error like this.

[image]

I understand it's gonna check whether the email exists or not. But I don't know why I posted all my attributes but the backend seems not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that your controller is looking at `params[:user]` to find the user's information but you don't have `:user` in your `params`. [The manual](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-rails) talks about this:

> **Working with Rails**
>   [...]
>   Similarly, Backbone PUTs and POSTs direct JSON representations of models, where by default Rails expects namespaced attributes. You can have your controllers filter attributes directly from `params`, or you can override toJSON in Backbone to add the extra wrapping Rails expects.

So adjust your controller to look at `params` rather than at something inside `params` or adjust your Backbone model's `toJSON` to look something like this:

```
toJSON: function() {
    return { user: _.clone(this.attributes) };
}
```

If you change `toJSON` you'll want to adjust how you feed data to your templates to compensate for the `toJSON` return value change.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that's the problem. One trick I thought would work was add 'paramRoot: "user"` in backbone model, but it seems failed.